# Changing directory of package install in aws sagemaker

Tags: amazon-web-services, jupyter-notebook, amazon-sagemaker

I am trying to install packages to /dev/nvme1n1 but it keeps installing the packages to /dev/nvme0n1p1. I am running a jupyter notebook on aws sagemaker[image]

Comment: my pip install statements install to `/home/ec2-user` by default (under python site packages folder), what location does your `pip show <pkg>` display?